# Please Add a VSO Tag

Tags: support, status-completed

Should there be a tag for VSO.  My organization exclusively uses the Microsoft stack and so I have questions I would like to tag with VSO to indicate that I'm using Visual Studio Online, as opposed to the on premise TFS/VSTS for my build/release/test agents

Answer (score 1):

Tags are created when added to a question, you need 150 reputation to [create tags](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

In those cases where you don't have enough reputation to create them, drop a line at end of your question on main site so someone can add it to your question.

I've added the [vso](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vso) to one of your question, you can now go and complete its wiki and excerpt.